.NET 8 runtime installed without admin rights
I have an application which have a single file installation which does not require admin rights. I would like to migrate it to .NET 8, but I'm not sure hot to manage the runtime installation.
I can see they can somehow be installed for a local user, but its purpose is just for continuous integration...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script#description
Is that an usable approach? Or is there any other method I can use?
I would like to avoid to make a self-contained app, since I don't want to be in charge of .NET security updates.

Why do you want to install the .NET Runtime on the target computer without admin privileges? Do you not want it to be installed for all users of the computer?

My advice is that you go with the self-contained app. I don't see why you should care about security updates for whatever app you are making. I don't see e.g. a quickly made program on a company share as a target for hackers just because it is self-contained.

Do you know for sure your target computer does not have .NET 8 installed? Why not just have it installed, by an admin if necessary?

Is the "manage the runtime installation" original problem? It's not clear what scenario you have, but I see no problem to inform user about update and help them to get it, but let installer completely handle the rest (and it will likely need admin rights).

In .NET 8 you can create a single-file self-contained executable that contains both the application and runtime code in a single .exe. You can copy that without requiring admin rights. It will be a bit big though.
